# Select arguments from mysql general log

Tags: mysql

What i'm trying to do is select the deleted rows and inserted rows and changed rows from a specific TABLE called BOOK from mysql.

```
set global general_log='ON';
set global log_output='TABLE';

SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log 
WHERE command_type = 'Query' 
AND argument LIKE 'Insert %';
```

Is there anything else I can further add into the argument function? like to make it more defined to search for specific table name.
I can use multiple selects so probably 1 for Insert, 1 for delete and 1 for changes.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: anyone know how to select arguments from log?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(argument, ' ', 1), 
       COUNT(*) 
FROM   mysql.general_log 
WHERE  argument LIKE '%INTO%' 
        OR argument LIKE '%FROM%' 
        or argument LIKE '%SET%' 
GROUP  BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(argument, ' ', 1);
```